# php.ini getting updated without getting replaced

Tags: php, installation

My product gets shipped with PHP binaries, dlls, php.ini in folder PHP.

Now I have updated the PHP binaries to recent version (5.3.6 from 4.33) in my installer package. So When the product is installed on existing installation (upgraded) the files under PHP directory gets replaced. But the config file php.ini gets updated by itself with new attributes instead of getting replaced totally.

How can I replace config file php.ini completely without just upgrading its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply deleting it. (backup!)

It's a matter of how you are running PHP but it worked once for me.

Or you try downloading a [clean version (untested)](https://siteworks.com/support/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=3)

Using [ini_restore](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-restore.php) could also be an option.

Comment: ini_restore()... Cool, did not know about this function.

Answer (score 1):

I add an additional `zzz_rock_n_roll.ini` file into the folder for additional .ini files in debian it's `/etc/php5/conf.d`. Since this file has a zzz prefix it is included last and overwrites all other settings of the main and all other additional ini files. Therefore I'm always save with upgrades.